# Rails: create one dimensional array from multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a multi dimensional array: @line_items

It has links with models, product and user.

I want to generate a single dimensional array from @line_items which will contain emails of user.

Something like this:

```
 emails = @line_items.product.user.email
```

But it is not working and gives error:

```
 undefined method `user' for #<Array:0xb1a12e74>
```

For single line_item it works.

```
 email = @line_item.product.user.email
```

I tried to generate array like this:

```
    @line_items.each do |i|
        @foodio.each do |j|
            @foodio[j] = i.product.user.email
        end
    end
```

But it gives

```
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

As foodio is nil.

Can any body help here?

Thanks for reading!

**UPDATE**

My UserMailer model:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "email@mealnut.com"

  def welcome_email(user, order)
@user = user
    @order = order
    @line_items = @order.line_items
    @foodio = @line_items.map do |line_item|
  line_item.product.user.email
end   

    mail(:to => user.email, :cc => ["care@mealnut.com", "#{foodio}"], :subject => "Order no. #{order.id}")
   end

  end
```

Order Controller:

```
 def process_order
   @order = current_order
   @line_items = @order.line_items
    if @line_items.size > 0
         session[:order_id] = nil
         UserMailer.welcome_email(current_user, @order).deliver
    else
      render :action => "cart"
   end

 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
array_of_emails = @line_items.map do |line_item|
  line_item.product.user.email
end
```

**UPD**. If you have truly mutidimentinal array, use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
my_array = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
my_array.flatten # => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: I am doing this in UserMailer model. As need to cc emails. Added user solution in UserMailer model but it gives error "undefined method `encoding' for #<Array:0xacd0528>" for order_controller. In order_controller, UserMailer.welcome_email(current_user, @order).deliver

Comment: user2206724, can you please update the question with additional details about UserMailer/OrderController? Specifically, include the code which raises `undefined method 'encoding' for #<Array:0xacd0528>`

Comment: added the UserMailer and ordercontroller, the way it gives error

Comment: I guess this line is issue: :cc => ["care@mealnut.com", "#{@foodio}"]. It is not taking care mail and foodio mails. How to make this work?

Comment: user2206724, change this `:cc => ["care@mealnut.com", "#{@foodio}"]` to this `:cc => ["care@mealnut.com"] + @foodio`

Comment: Cool gmile. It worked awesomely. Hitting my head on this from past few hours. Thanks a ton :-)